# Fixing edge/pixel defects in image

Tags: image-processing

I have a large number of images that are supposed to look something like the top part of the image:

[image]

Instead, some have defects in them, as in the bottom part of the image. As you can see, there are 2 types of defects:

1. **Outliers**: These are pixels (or small areas) of one colour located in a vast area of another colour.
2. **Missing edges**: These are black areas on the edges between two (non-black) colours.

There's also a third defect in some images, which is blur on the edges, but I think I can deal with that myself.

I'm looking for a way to automatically fix these images so that:

1. The outliers get replaced with the colour they're located in (so a red pixel in the green area gets painted green).
2. The missing edges get coloured in with the outer colour (so the black edge on the boundary between green and red gets painted green).
3. The rest of the image is left as is.
4. No additional defects (such as blur or image noise) are introduced in the process. The only colours present in the 3 ellipses should be (0,255,0), (255,0,0), (0,0,255).

Is such an automatic process possible using some kind of filter-based method or would I have to do this with some clever if-then rules for handling pixels based on their neighbourhoods?

Comment: I would say it is a mixture of those methods you hint at. Are these areas uniform or are they textured in your original images?

Comment: The outer part is not uniform - it's in truth a photograph, but I can easily replace it with the uniform black area as pictured above. The green, red, and blue areas are uniform (0,255,0), (255,0,0) and (0,0,255) (other than some images that have blur in them, as described in the question).

Comment: Can I please ask if this was resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at for this problem is a combination of "Image Segmentation" and "Spatial Analysis".

The image segmentation part of this particular task is very simple because each pixel "class" is already labeled by a colour. You might need an additional labeling step because (for example) the blue class contains two **disjoint** areas, but this is easily dealt with via a simple [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). (We will come back to this in more detail).

The more challenging bit here is what corresponds to *relationships* expressed in natural language as "the blue areas **inside** the red areas", or "the black areas **adjacent** to red areas" and so on. These are relationships that correspond to mathematical "queries" such as "Point on line", "Point within area", "Area within area" and so on.

For example, to determine if a point is within a circle, all you have to test for is whether the distance from the centre of that circle to the point in question is less than the radius of the circle. To test a point within a rectangle you would test if its coordinates are within the boundaries of the rectangle and so on.

As you may have guessed, this does not sound easy to generalise (e.g. any kind of polygon, whether in 2D or 3D or higher dimensions etc). Fortuneatly, there are a lot of good libraries out there that implement geometrical primitives, operations and relationships for us to make such tasks easier.

In the case of Python there is [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). Shapely contains primitives such as `Point, Line, Polygon` and others as well as operators and relationships you can use to "query" their spatial relationships.

Here is a very simple example that answers part of your task: Is one area within another area?
Notice here, I simply wrote "area" as this is defined by an "unordered" set of pixels similar to what you would get out of simple queries such as "Give me all pixels in an image that are red".

```
    import shapely.geometry

    Q = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint([(u,v) for u in range(0,10) for v in range(0,10)])
    W = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint([(u,v) for u in range(5,8) for v in range(5,8)])
```

With these two lines we have created two `MultiPoint` (areas composed of many `Point`s) "areas": One big one from `(0,0)` to `(9,9)` and one small one from `(5,5)` to `(7,7)`. Furthermore, the small "patch" is **contained** by the bigger "patch".

Let's probe that relationship

```
    Q.contains(W)
```

This should return `True`

```
   W.contains(Q)
```

This should return `False`.

You might be wondering what would happen if what we called the "small patch" contained two disjoint patches. In that case, Shapely would respond with `False` if only one of the patches was found within a testing area.

The black areas are a bit more challenging. You might think that their case is covered by the [`.touches()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.touches) relationship but "touching" implies some sort of overlap and there are no criteria here by which to make those areas somehow to overlap. **But** what you can probe instead is **distance**.

In the case of `MultiPoint` objects, the distance between two objects is the shortest possible distance between their points. Again, here is a minimal example:

```
    import shapely.geometry

    Q = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint([(u,v) for u in range(0,10) for v in range(0,10)])
    W = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint([(u,v) for u in range(0,10) for v in range(12,22)])
```

Notice the differences in the way the "boxes" are setup here. To get the distance between them:

```
    Q.distance(W)
```

This should return `3`.

You can see here that the black areas distance to blue, red and green is 1 (they are adjacent). Therefore, to locate which parts is a given black part adjacent to, you just assess its distance from the parts of interest.

So, with this bit out of the way, let's get back to how you would segment/label your pixel masks.

If your regions where not overlapping it would be extremely simple to extract the pixel coordinates that correspond to all pixels that have a specific color and create `MultiPoint` instances from them. Here is an example using Python's `numpy` and Shapely.

```
    import skimage.io
    import numpy
    import shapely.geometry

    # Read the image
    I = skimage.io.imread("someRRGBimage.png")
    # Exrtact the pixels that are equal to a specific value
    pixel_bunch = numpy.where((I[:,:,0]==the_red) & (I[:,:,1]==the_green) & (I[:,:,2]==the_blue)) # Notice here the_red, the_green, the_blue are the components of the area's colour.
    # Create a MultiPoint patch
    point_patch = shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(list(zip(pixel_bunch[0], pixel_bunch[1])));
```

But if you try to select the blues or the reds out of the image you are providing, you will get one large area, plus disjoint little ones and if you try to pass those through the spatial relationship analysis we are talking about above, they would fail.

The simplest way to split them apart is to use connectivity labeling. This works by scanning a binary image and assigning a different number to regions that are not connected. This basically inserts an extra step to the extraction of the pixel values above, as you would first have to create the mask image for a specific colour, then label that mask and finally create the regions based on the identified (and by now isolated) regions.

It's far easier to demonstrate this over grayscale images:

```
    import skimage.io
    import skimage.measure
    import numpy
    import Shapely.geometry

    # Read the image
    I = skimage.io.imread("someRRGBimage.png")
    # Work on the Red channel
    mask = (I[:,:,0]==255)
    labeled_mask = skimage.measure.label(mask)
    pixel_bunch = numpy.where(labeled_mask==some_patch_id) # Notice here some_patch_id is the zero based index of some isolated patch that has been labeled in the image.
    # Create a MultiPoint patch
    ...
    ...
```

It is not a difficult task but it sure is messy.

Finally, two notes:

1. You will probably have to re-colour those areas between the red and the blue that are currently black and leave black for the "background".
2. The complexity of deriving those relationships scales with the size of the regions, sometimes taking tens of seconds (or more) for very large `MultiPoint` sets. In that case, it might be more practical to work with polygons. This inserts yet another step just before deriving `point_patch` where you first derive the boundary of the identified pixel area and **then** instantiate a `Polygon` from that boundary. Operations between polygons will be much quicker.

Hope this helps.